# Appending a new node or a child node using Dom4j

Tags: java, xml, append, dom4j

I am stuck at updating an existing XML document. I have to add another element to the root node. I need to append it, but using `XMLWriter`, it is overriding the object and all the old data is lost. How can I add another node to the exisitng document?

That is, appending. I am using the [Dom4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dom4j) library.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLWriter` is not the way to go. You can append, delete or otherwise manipulate nodes quite easily using the methods in the Node class and its subclasses. For example:

```
Element root = document.getRootElement();
Element author = root.addElement("author");
```

Comment: how to load an existing document to append more data and save it once the job is done? dom4j doesn't have much support:(

Comment: @user896456, why don't you read the documentation at http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/ ? Start with the cookbook section.